# Which environment are comfortable for RE ( Free tool )

Tags: windows, linux

- #### I'm a beginner in RE. So i don't know which environments are better for me ( Linux or Window , 32bit or 64bit ).
- #### Which free tools are the best for each OS .

  Ollydbg is for Windows 32bit right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a "better environment" or "best tools", its all up to the RE tasks you are up against.

Since you said you are a beginner and from reading between the lines without a pre determined task, I would recommend 32bit machine and Ollydbg focusing on solving some CrackMe challenges.

You can find some of them here:
[Tuts4You -  CrackMe](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.61)